# index error in python, please help to fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting error, please help to get it solved.

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui, time

N= int(input ("Number of URL's to be entered:"))
URL=[]
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

for i in range(1,N):
    str= 'Enter'+ str(i) + 'URL'
    print(str)
    URL[i]= input()

for i in range(1,N):
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url[i])
    time.sleep(10)
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    filename= "test"+ str(i)+ ".png"
    screenshot.save(filename)
```

Error:

Number of URL's to be entered:5

Enter1URL

https://discord.com/channels/423464391791476747/449411261491314698

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dilip\PycharmProjects\untitled3\sc1.py", line 11, in <module>
    URL[i]= input()
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: List indexing starts at 0, not 1, so you are going 1 past the end of the list.

Comment: also don't use `str` as an identifier inside your code. It creates unintended complications with the builtin `str()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an element to a list, you should use List_name.append(element).

Also, The first URL element's index is 0 not 1.
This should do the job:

```
for i in range(0,N):
a = input(f"Enter {str(i)} URL")
URL.append(a)
```

URL[0] will contain the first element, and URL[N-1] the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty list in line 5:

```
URL=[]
```

Then you access the second element of the list in line 11. This gives you an error since the list has zero elements. I guess you want to add an element to list instead of accessing the second element. Use the append function. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html .

Answer (score 0):

See below how the loop of collection URl's should look like

```
N = 5
URL = []
for i in range(1, N):
    URL.append(input(f'Enter URL {i}'))

print(URL)
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\dilip\PycharmProjects\untitled3\sc1.py", line 9, in <module>
    str= 'Enter'+ str(i) + 'URL'
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to index an empty list.

If you want to add elements to the list, use the [append()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method

```
for i in range(1,N):
    str= 'Enter'+ str(i) + 'URL'
    print(str)
    URL.append(input())
```